# My Chrome extension isn't a NPAPI Plugin, but the Web Store complains it is. Is or isn't it a NPAPI Plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, npapi

I am creating a Chrome extension, however, it constantly needs to be reviewed due to the Web Store thinking it is a NPAPI Plugin. I have done my research and I can't figure out why Web Store is saying it's a NPAPI Plugin. Here's my manifest file, if that helps.

```
    {
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Kwik Note",
  "description": "A quick and easy to use note maker",
  "version": "1.0.1",

  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "storage"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
         "19": "icon19.png",
         "38": "icon38.png"
      },
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "icons": {
      "128": "icon128.png",
      "48": "icon48.png",
      "16": "icon16.png"
   },

 "background": {
    "scripts":  [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["jquery.min.js", "jquery-ui.js", "create.js"],
        "css": ["theme.css"]
    }],

    "options_page": "options.html"
}
```

Could you please me how to make my extension not be flagged as a NPAPI Plugin.